# How to pass data externally to specflow(version 3.7) feature file from excel file?

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I am trying to write a simple feature file which has a scenario to add two numbers. i am making use of data driven approach, but unfortunately i couldn't use specflow+excel package in specflow version 3.7. It is stated in official documentation that it has been deprecated for version above 2.0. what could be the solution for this?

calc.feature

```
Feature: CalcExcel
    Testing Calculator using data driven approach

@smoke
Scenario Outline: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is <num1>
    And the second number is <num2>
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be <result>
@source:data.xlsx:Sheet1
Examples:
        | num1 | num2 | result |
```

Error i am getting while building the project is **Scenario Outline Add two numbers has no examples defined**

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `<specflow>` tag in App.config or the contents of specflow.json? Is the Excel file copied to the output when building the solution? What if you add a blank line about the `@source` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to call this a bug in specflow external data plugin.
Although this can be fixed very easily by doing the below:

```
Feature: CalcExcel
Testing Calculator using data driven approach

@smoke
@source:data.xlsx:Sheet1
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is <num1>
    And the second number is <num2>
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be <result>
```

This will yied exactly the same result as scenario outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SpecFlow.ExternalData** package to pass data externally from Excel file.
[image: Specflow.ExternalData]

You can use your feature like following:

```
Feature: CalcExcel
    Testing Calculator using data driven approach

@smoke @DataSource:data.xlsx @DataSet:Sheet1
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given the first number is <num1>
    And the second number is <num2>
    When the two numbers are added
    Then the result should be <result>
```

You can use **Scenario** instead of **Scenario Outline**.
You don't need to add **Examples**. For more information see: [External Data Plugin](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Guides/externaldata.html#excel-files)